# problems with xpath evaluation

Tags: xpath

If I want to extract hrefs only under Type1, basically, 1,2,3,4. htm but not including 5.htm, how to do that?

What I have for now is ://table[@class='leftnav']//a"

Thanks !

```
<table width="240" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="leftnav">
  <tr class="leftnav">
    <th>Type1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="leftnav">
    <td><a href="/mic/1.htm">2013</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="leftnav">
    <td><a href="/mic/2.htm">2012</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="leftnav">
    <td><a href="/mic/3.htm">2011</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="leftnav">
    <td><a href="/mic/4.htm">2010</a></td>
  </tr>
   <tr class="leftnav">
    <th>Type2</th>
  </tr>
   <tr class="leftnav">
     <td><a href="/mic/5.htm">2013</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this xpath:

```
//tr[(preceding-sibling::tr/th)[last()]="Type1"]/td/a
```